# Mongo Java drivers & mappers performances

Tags: mongodb, mongomapper, morphia, jongo

Mongo in Java can be used with several tools:

- the 10gen [official driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Tutorial)
- an alternative [async Java driver](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver)
- a mapper — a library built on top of a driver — [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia), [Jongo](http://www.jongo.org)... (*see [complete list](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Language+Center#JavaLanguageCenter-POJOMappers)*)

Is there some benchmarks comparing mappers to drivers performances and one versus each others?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there are no benchmarks that I am aware of. The driver home page is [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Drivers) (but I'm guessing that you probably know that) and the [Java Language Center](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Language+Center) containing all information related to Java for MongoDB.

There is quite a bit of work going on with the Java drivers at present afaik but no benchmarks.