# How to avoid that much casts with MongoDb Java-Api

Tags: mongodb, casting, java

HI i'm working with the Java-Api of mongo-db.

I have to cast verry often like this

```
BasicDBList points = ((BasicDBList) ((BasicDBObject) currentObject.get("poly")).get("coordinates"));
```

which is not fun. Am i missing something or it is just the way to do it?

i think BasicDBObject should have functions like

```
BasicDBObject getBasicDBObject(String key)
BasicDBList getBasicDBList(String key)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the current java driver is not perfect and it is difficult to avoid casting as you mentioned. However, java driver team is [working on the next version](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/58136652766/the-mongodb-java-driver-3-0) and as far as I understand it will be completely rewritten.

In one of the mongodb meetup I heard that the new version will make use of asynchronous API, similar to the node driver. I guess we need to sit tight and wait for the next major release.
Alternatives, are (from [Mongo Java drivers & mappers performances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914006)):

- [async Java driver](http://www.allanbank.com/mongodb-async-driver/)
- a library built on top of a driver, e.g. [Morphia](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia), [Jongo](http://jongo.org/), see [POJOMappers](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/java/#JavaLanguageCenter-POJOMappers)

Comment: thanks, is there any alternative for the default java driver? Or is it possible to access a beta of the new driver?

Comment: @wutzebaer There are two other alternatives, look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12914006/